# Average of a list of numbers without sum function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum, average

I want to getting average of list without using the `sum()` function. This is my code:

```
sample_list = [2, 10, 3, 5]

sample_listSum =[sample_list[0]+ sample_list[1]+ sample_list[2]+ sample_list[3]]

sample_listLength = len(sample_list)

sample_listAvrage = sample_listSum / sample_listLength

print("This is result of list", sample_listAvrage)
```

But it's not working, may I ask you help me about it?

Comment: your sample_listSum is a list, this should be a value

Comment: Change `sample_listSum =[sample_list[0]+ sample_list[1]+ sample_list[2]+ sample_list[3]]` to `sample_listSum =sample_list[0]+ sample_list[1]+ sample_list[2]+ sample_list[3]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = [2, 10, 3, 5]
>>> a = 0
>>> 
>>> for i in s:
...     a += i
... 
>>> print a
20
>>> mean = a / float(len(s))
>>> mean
5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd line is creating a new list, you need to remove the brackets

```
sample_list = [2, 10, 3, 5]
sample_listSum = sample_list[0] + sample_list[1] + sample_list[2] + sample_list[3]
sample_listLength = len(sample_list)
sample_listAvrage = sample_listSum / sample_listLength
print("This is the result of list", sample_listLength)
>> This is result of list 5.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. why when I run the code my result is 4 not 5?

Comment: I am not sure, which version of Python are you using ?

Comment: I'm using python 3, of course I running the code on ubuntu like this $python3 code.py

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the brackets:

```
sample_listSum = sample_list[0]+ sample_list[1]+ sample_list[2]+ sample_list[3]
```

However you could also calculate it using [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) (it's not the `sum` function):

```
>>> import statistics
>>> statistics.mean(sample_list)
5
```

Answer (score -1):

My new code and correct answer:

```
sample_list = [2, 10, 3, 5]

x =[sample_list[0]+ sample_list[1]+ sample_list[2]+ sample_list[3]]

b = len (sample_list)

avrage = x / b

print("This is result of list", avrage)
```